# Problems with CAS validation and mod_auth_cas

Tags: apache, authentication, cookies, cas

So I have an Apache server running with the mod_auth_cas module. I'm trying to have a certain secure directory protected. I load the module in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule auth_cas_module /usr/lib64/php/modules/mod_auth_cas.so
```

And have all of the configuration for it loaded from a cas.conf file:

```
CASVersion 1

CASDebug On


CASRootProxiedAs http://something.com/secure
CASLoginURL https://secure.its.somewhere.edu/cas/login
CASValidateURL https://secure.its.somewhere.edu/cas/servlet/validate

CASCookiePath /var/www/webroot/CAS/

<Directory /var/www/webroot/ROOT/secure>
    AuthType CAS
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

When I visit the secure directory, the website does redirect me to a CAS login page, and does send me back with a ticket after I've logged in. However I get a 401 Authorization Required page. I looked through the Apache logs and this is what I've found:

```
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(2026): [client ] Entering cas_authenticate()
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(575): [client ] CAS Service 'http%3a%2f%2fsomething.com%2fsecure%2fsecure'
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(523): [client ] entering getCASLoginURL()
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(500): [client ] entering getCASGateway()
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(590): [client ] entering redirectRequest()
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(602): [client ] Adding outgoing header: Location: https://secure.its.somewhere.edu/cas/login?service=http%3a%2f%2fsomething.com%2fsecure%2fsecure
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(2026): [client ] Entering cas_authenticate()
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(645): [client ] Modified r->args (now '')
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(1729): [client ] entering getResponseFromServer()
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(575): [client ] CAS Service 'http%3a%2f%2fsomewhere.com%2fsecure%2fsecure%2fsecure'
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(1806): [client ] Validation response: no\n\n
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(1434): [client ] entering isValidCASTicket()
[debug] mod_auth_cas.c(1440): [client 73.163.185.61] MOD_AUTH_CAS: response = no\n\n
```

I've looked in the file that the cookie should be saved, and there are no cookies.

I've been looking up documentation for CAS and trying to figure out why on earth its not working. I followed all of the documentation to set up the Apache module. I'm completely confused. Any help?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the location of the apache debug logs? I am facing the same issue and unable to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after tearing my hair out for a while and trying all sorts of Apache configuration changes, recompiling the module, and reading through even more documentation, I found the small, but annoying, bug.

```
CASRootProxiedAs http://something.com/secure
```

This doesn't work. It has to be proxied as:

```
CASRootProxiedAs http://something.com
```

Simple bug. Had me tearing my hair out for a few days.